# How can you force a class that implements a interface also extend an other class?

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, extends

Is it possible to make a class that implements my interface to automatically also extend another class? 
More specific I want my implementation always to be an extension of Thread.
Or for that matter implementing Runnable, but public interface Name implements someInterface  seems so wrong...

```
public interface userValidTimer extends Thread {
}
```

However this gives me an error in netbeans.

Comment: Interfaces can only extend other interfaces. Interfaces cannot extend classes. Interfaces do not implement other interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can you force a class that implements a interface also extend an other class?

You can't.

However, if you turn the interface into an abstract class, it will work:

```
public abstract class UserValidTimer extends Thread {
    // add suitable constructors ...
    // add your interface methods here as abstract methods.
}
```

---

But there is another thing to point out.  Generally speaking implementing a thread by extending the `Thread` class is a bad idea.  In most cases, the better option is to implement your custom thread logic in a `Runnable` and pass an instance of the runnable to a vanilla Thread as a constructor argument; e.g. using an anonymous `Runnable` class.

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run() { /* put your thread logic here */ }
    });
```

Why?  Because you can easily modify this so that the runnable can be handed to a thread pool, an executor or a fork-join pool for execution.

Comment: Good point on not extending Thread. Separating the logic and threading concerns.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot force all classes that implement an interface to extend a particular class, because that would defeat the purpose of an interface.

However, if you put the methods of your interface into an abstract class that extends the base class of your choice, you would be able to achieve the same effect without an interface. In other words, instead of this

```
interface MyInterface {
    void methodOne();
    void methodTwo();
}
```

do this:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass extends TheClassYouWantToExtend {
    public abstract void methodOne();
    public abstract void methodTwo();
}
```

Comment: So can you use "abstract class" to "code to interface" ?

Comment: @DenUil Yes, you can. The word "interface" in "coding to an interface" does not mean "Java interface". It means "a set of related operations". As long as you use `MyAbstractClass` as the static type of objects whose runtime type extends `MyAbstractClass`, your code can be legitimately described as "coding to interface".

Answer (score 0):

interface cannot extend class. What you need is

```
public class MyClass extends MySuperClass implements MyInterface{ }
```